# FFmpeg: Error when using encoding options copied from Mediainfo

Tags: ffmpeg

This is my command line:

```
ffmpeg -i i.mp4 -i i.png -c:v libx264 -x264-params cabac=1:ref=8:deblock=1,0,0:analyse=0x3,0x113:me=umh:subme=9:psy_rd=1.0,0.0:mixed_ref=1:me_range=64:chroma_me=1:trellis=2:8x8dct=1:cqm=0:deadzone=21,11:chroma_qp_offset=-2:threads=3:nr=0:decimate=1:mbaff=0:bframes=5:b_pyramid=1:b_adapt=2:b_bias=0:direct=3:wpredb=1:keyint=300:keyint_min=1:scenecut=54:rc=2pass:bitrate=75:ratetol=1.0:qcomp=0.64:qpmin=8:qpmax=51:qpstep=4:cplxblur=20.0:qblur=0.5:ip_ratio=1.40:pb_ratio=1.30:aq=1,1.00 -c:a copy -filter_complex 'overlay' o1.mp4
```

And ffmpeg said:

```
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] Error parsing option 'mixed_ref = 1'.
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] Error parsing option 'deadzone = 21,11'.
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] Error parsing option 'decimate = 1'.
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] Error parsing option 'mbaff = 0'.
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] Error parsing option 'direct = 3'.
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] Error parsing option 'wpredb = 1'.
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] Error parsing option 'rc = 2pass'.
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] Error parsing option 'ip_ratio = 1.40'.
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] Error parsing option 'pb_ratio = 1.30'.
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] Error parsing option 'aq = 1,1.00'.
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] can't open file '0'
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

No need to declare dozens of options. That's what the x264 encoding presets are for. Your output indicates that the *slower* preset was used:

```
ffmpeg -i i.mp4 -i i.png -filter_complex 'overlay' -c:v libx264 -preset slower -c:a copy o1.mp4
```

- I could tell which preset was used by referring to `x264 --fullhelp`.
- This will use CRF as the rate control method. Your output used 2-pass mode. Unless you need to target a specific output file size (you probably don't), then just use CRF. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for a 2-pass example and more info on presets and CRF.

Comment: But if I do want to declare dozens of options, how can I get it pass without getting errors?

Comment: @Yark What's wrong with the preset?

Comment: I said I want to use encoding options copied from Mediainfo.

Comment: @Yark Someone probably just used a preset. It's a waste of time and effort to do it piecemeal.

Comment: Since you have started calling a question you can not answer "a waste of time and effort", thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Errors as these:

```
[libx264 @ 000001ded1a53d60] Error parsing option 'mixed_ref = 1'.
```

come directly from x264's `x264_param_parse()` function, which ffmpeg uses.

It turns out that x264 reports the failing options differently than what it expects when setting them. You can correlate the two using x264's source code:

- You can tell which internal variables are printed in [the x264_param2string() function in x264's code base](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264/-/blob/04e6c65e/common/base.c#L1319).
- You can check which options x264 expects when setting these variables in [the `param_parse()` function](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264/-/blob/04e6c65e/common/base.c#L815).

I looked up some of these mismatches, and it turns out that this is what you need to use:

```
╔══════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ printed value    ║ setting                                   ║
╠══════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ mixed_ref        ║ mixed-refs                                ║
║ deadzone = X,Y   ║ deadzone-inter=X:deadzone-intra=Y         ║
║ decimate         ║ dct-decimate                              ║
║ direct = 0/1/2/3 ║ direct="none"/"spatial"/"temporal"/"auto" ║
║ rc               ║ implied by qp, abr, crf, 2-pass mode...   ║
║ ...              ║                                           ║
╚══════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Especially "rc" shows that there's not enough of an exact correlation to make this easily reverse-engineerable. That's why it may be easier trying to match the values to one of x264's presets.